# Trigger Alexa speaking

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'd like to be able to remotely cause Alexa to say something on my Echo.

A specific use case would be to notify my wife that I'm leaving work. I currently use Waze to do this, but it would be very convenient if Alexa could be triggered to say "Ron is on his way home" also.

I've talked with people about this, and I don't think Amazon supports this yet. I'm posting here to give us a place to find out if/when that support happens, or inform us if it is somehow possible now.

Comment: You're correct that this isn't possible - beyond that there's really not a question here, so this isn't really an on-topic post for Stack Overflow's Q&A format.

Comment: There were rumors in September about this feature but nothing panned out (http://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/9/8/12848586/amazon-alexa-echo-speaker-push-notifications-rumor) I got around the issue by having a little RaspberryPi using Alexa as a bluetooth speaker and using TTS there.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. However, you could launch a skill via a Routine.

An Alexa routine consists of a trigger and a sequence of actions. The trigger is an event such as a time of day (for example, 7:00 AM) or a user request such as, "Alexa, start my Morning Session".

Please check the following blog post for further details:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2019/10/tell-your-customers-they-can-now-invoke-your-skill-from-routines

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/integrate-custom-task-with-alexa-routines.html#what-are-alexa-routines