# Trigger notification on specific Alexa device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I saw a few posts with similar question but they are all outdated and not really answered. The idea is to trigger a notification on a specific Alexa device. For example through another Alexa in the same network or over phone remotely. Before I get my hands dirty is something like this possible at all?

Here is a similar question [Trigger Alexa speaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088376/trigger-alexa-speaking)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is **Proactive Events**.

What you can do is use these APIs in your skill to send notification to the customers of your Alexa skill to their respective Alexa devices.

Alexa Docs for ProactiveEventsAPI :

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html

They support a set of pre-defined templates(schemas) for different type of notifications that can be sent. These are listed here:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/schemas-for-proactive-events.html

If you don't find the one suitable for your use case they also provide you option in the same schema listing page to submit your request to them.

Alexa's developer blog on the same with link to step-by-step building instructions for a demo skill which uses ProactiveEvents API:

https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/bbf23596-766a-4e7c-8d74-cbfc234b6791/how-to-send-media-event-notifications-to-your-alexa-skill-customers

Other resources I found on web for the same which might be useful:

- https://www.jovo.tech/tutorials/alexa-notifications-proactive-events
- https://datavizz.in/blog/alexa/2019/04/18/send-notifications-to-users-using-Alexa.html

Answer (score 0):

The Proactive Events API can target a specific user_id (amazon account), but at this point I haven't discovered any way to narrow that down to a specific device.